How can I fix this jenkins error I am getting while pushing to GCP Artifact registry
I wrote a Jenkins Pipeline to push to gcp artifact registry, I can't tell why I get this error Error: trying to reuse blob sha256:617df26c9e2bec4e63eed45acaa78b253ac74e1cd0dd74da35b050f3ef707d47 at destination: Requesting bearer token: invalid status code from registry 400 (Bad Request). anyone know what the issue might be ?
enter code here

         steps {
             script {
                 dir('lil-node-app') {
                       sh "docker build -t ${ARTIFACT_REGISTRY_URL}:${env.BUILD_NUMBER} ."
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     stage('Authenticate to Artifact Registry') {
         steps {
             script {
                 withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'gcp-poc', variable: 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')]) {
                     sh "gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"
                     sh "gcloud auth configure-docker us-east4-docker.pkg.dev --quiet"
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 
     stage('Push Docker Image') {
         steps {
              script {
                 withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'gcp-poc', variable: 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')]) {
                    sh 'cat "${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}" | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://us-east4-docker.pkg.dev'
                    sh "docker push ${ARTIFACT_REGISTRY_URL}:${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
                 }
             }
         }
     }  ```


Please don't include images in questions when it's trivial to copy-paste the text content. Images may not outlive questions and make it more difficult for others to reference their content. In this case, you would be more able to redact content too.

It's unclear from your image but it appears that you're trying to push to us-east4-docker.pkg.dev/{project}/operations-image:71. This does not include an artifact repository. The URL should be of the form us-east4-docker.pkg.dev/{project}/{repo}/operations-image:71
